# C# Winodws forms comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть windows form, мне нужно добавить в `comboBox` данные, которые вводит пользователь, НО требуется, чтобы `comboBox` отображал только имя. Например, добавляю данные о животном:

имя волк

вес 34

цвет черный

цена 100$

Вот из этого всего мне нужно, чтобы в `comboBox` было "ВОЛК". Но при этом данные должны сохраниться. То есть вес, цвет и цена должны быть каким-то образом сохранены для отображения в будущем.

[image: картинка]

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте добавление данных о волке в комбобокс выборочное (что вам нужно там, имя например только), а остальные данные записывайты, либо в массив (если данные будут храниться только в рамках одной сессии), либо записывайте данные в базу данных (на крайний случай в текстовый файл, если данные надо хранить на протяжение долгого времени).